# Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context. Linq to SQL

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I have a table "Components" that contains columns "AssemblyGuid" and "PartGuid".
And I have a components list "componentsGuids"

```
 var componentsGuids = _input.Select(x =>
            new Component
            {
                AssemblyGuid = x.AssemblyGuid,
                PartGuid = x.DetailGuid,
            }).ToList();
```

How to make a Linq To Sql query that loads all Components entries that are in the "componentsGuids" list by composite key?

```
   var componentsDb = Context.Components//.ToList() an error occurs here
            .Where(
                x => componentsGuids.Any(
                    y => y.AssemblyGuid == x.AssemblyGuid
                    && y.PartGuid == x.PartGuid));
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that helps you to find a solution. I'm not sure if the code is working like that out of the box, but I hope it makes the idea clear. Concat your two guids in a list and use `Contains` to check for the existence of the also concatenated guid pair.

Something like that should work:

```
var componentsGuidsConcat = componentsGuid
    .Select(p => AssemblyGuid.ToString() + PartGuid.ToString())
    .ToList();

var componentsDb = Context.Components
    .Where(p => componentsGuidsConcat.Contains(
        p.AssemblyGuid.ToString() + p.PartGuid.ToString())
    );
```

Comment: Sorry, but your code throws an exception. {"Internal error: An expression services limit has been reached. Please look for potentially complex expressions in your query, and try to simplify them."}

Comment: It should not be an out-of-the-box working code example. It should give you an idea on how you could solve your problem. I don't understand why you get such an exception. The query is all but complex...

Comment: your code works fine. however, if componentsGuidsConcat contains more than 1000 elements, an exception is thrown

Comment: Yes that is right. This is because of a limit of sql server. In that case maybe you should select all the (unfiltered) data to the client and then do the filtering. But then it might be, that you select a lot of data, that you actually don't and which could make your query slow.

Comment: In my case, I have more than 50,000 records per request

Comment: Where does this huge amount of guids come from, that you want to filter by? Is there maybe a way to simplify your software architecture to decrease it?